# Prevent Changing Exit Node

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, circuit

How to prevent changing exit node when browsing?
(same IP address until browser restart)

Note that it is not enough for me to specify just certain domains to have one IP - all domain visits must have same IP

Currently I have same IP address by using only one exit node
(which I believe to be insecure)

```
ExitNodes _____
StrictExitNodes 1
NewCircuitPeriod 3600
MaxCircuitDirtiness 3600
```

---

**EDIT:** @SuperSluether - I believe it is even more insecure by having the same IP across *all* sessions, rather than just the current session

Comment: Please read your own question. You just asked how to get the same IP address until the browser restarts, then said you believe it to be insecure by having the same IP address. If you need the same IP, perhaps a VPN would be better suited, as Tor is *designed* to change IPs.